# Item isn't adding in the to-do list in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I followed the tutorial from apple and made the to-do list app in objective c in xcode 6. But for some reason, when I type the items name in the textfield while the app runs in the simulator, and press 'save', it isn't adding in the list of the to-do items.

```
@interface ToDoListTableViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *toDoItems;

@end

@implementation ToDoListTableViewController

- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    AddToDoItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    ToDoItem *item = source.toDoItem;
    if (item != nil) {
        [self.toDoItems addObject:item];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self loadInitialData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (void)loadInitialData {
    ToDoItem *item1 = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    item1.itemName = @"Buy milk";
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item1];
    ToDoItem *item2 = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    item2.itemName = @"Buy eggs";
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item2];
    ToDoItem *item3 = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    item3.itemName = @"Read a book";
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item3];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:     (NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.toDoItems count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@" ListPrototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ToDoItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;
    return cell;
}
```

Here is the code from the addToDoItem file.

```
#import "AddToDoItemViewController.h"

@interface AddToDoItemViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *saveButton;

@end

@implementation AddToDoItemViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
} 

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
    if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {
        self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
        self.toDoItem.itemName = self.textField.text;
        self.toDoItem.completed = NO;
    }
}

@end
```

Here I am calling the unwindToList action.

```
@interface ToDoListTableViewController : UITableViewController

- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;

@end
```

Has anybody else the same problem or can somebody help me? I've already compared my codes and the codes in the tutorial but can't find any differences...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: after savebutton event, check values in `self.todoItem`, whether its same as what you have stored? Or it might be the tableview, which require to be reloaded.

Comment: Learn how to set breakpoints and examine the operation of your app.  I would start with a breakpoint in `unwindToList` and see what is happening

Comment: hope you linked the save button to the unwind action see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW7

Comment: Check whether unwindToList method is getting invoked?

Comment: the unwindToList method is invoked... @Rohit

Comment: the unwindToList method is linked with the save button too... @jpulikkottil

Comment: the tableview is reloaded, but what do you mean with the save button event? @Mrunal

Comment: Can you share your output screen?

Comment: @Holidaygirl : Once one taps on save button, either button event will get called, or prepareforsegue delegate. In that method, at the end check the `self.todoItem` list array, whether it is containing all the items or not?

Comment: if source.toDoItem is null it won't show. make sure it is not null. as @paulw11 says debugging is the best method to get going.